# "No value for" exception for getJSONArray

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a JSON object like this :

```
{
  "Successful": true,
  "Value": {
    "Materials":[{
      "MaterialID": 37628, 
      "MaterialID": 0, 
      "MaterialNo": 26868, 
      "Type": 0, 
      "MaterialName": Copper
    }],
    "Prices": []
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get materials array like this :

```
    public ArrayList<Material> parseMaterial (JSONObject object)
    {
     try
       {
         JSONArray materialArray = object.getJSONArray("Materials");
       }
      catch (JSONException e)
      {
       Log.d("JSONParser=>parseMaterial", e.getMessage());
      }
    }
```

I get this exception :

> JSONParser=>parseMaterial﹕ No value for Materials

Can you tell me what is wrong with the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a step: change

```
JSONArray materialArray = object.getJSONArray("Materials");
```

to

```
JSONObject value = object.getJSONObject("Value");
JSONArray materialArray = value.getJSONArray("Materials");
```

`getJSONArray` does not 'search' the entire object (this could give unpredictable results if you have multiple Materials in the object), only the first level.